# Nginx: Redirecting links with anchots to new pages

Tags: redirect, nginx

is it possible to redirect links, which have anchors in it to new pages?

Example:
http://website.com/dir/all-products#!Asus-Google Nexus 7 (2013)-Android-147
to
http://website.com/dir/name-of-prod/anotherid

Serversoftware: Nginx

Bye

Comment: You want to match the URL by it's hash ?

Comment: Yes, I have a list which looks like this: "/tablet-vergleich#!Acer-Iconia Tab W510-Windows-125" needs to be redirected to "/tablet-vergleich/acer-iconia-w510-10-1-zoll/457"

Answer (score 0):

Well the part of the URL (the hash) can't really be detected by the server, you need to handle it with javascript, after the page is loaded, using `location.hash`